# Add Person to Database with ArrayList field. Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, crud

Trying to create CRUD application  using jdbc and mysql. I have Person.class and two tables in Database:

```
class Person {
String name;
String surname;
List<String> phones;
}

Tables:    
`phone`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `owner` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_phone` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
  `person`
(
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `surname` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT `PK_phonebook` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ALTER TABLE `phone` 
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_phone_person`
    FOREIGN KEY (`owner`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE Cascade ON UPDATE Cascade
;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1 ;
```

How i can add person with field List phones to database using Servlets???
For example:
 Harry Smith +37521987902
                         +56727172713
                         +45679012214

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: How i can add person with field List phones to database using Servlets???

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple, you can use this way

1. Insert your person
2. get the id of that person
3. insert the list of phone

You can use it like this :

```
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_username, DB_password);

    String query = "INSERT INTO person (surname, name) values(?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "hello");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "jdbc");

    int affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    long id = 0;
    if (affectedRows > 0) {
        ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (generatedKeys.next()) {
            id = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no ID obtained.");
        }
    }

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO phone (owner, number) values(?, ?)");
    for (String phone : listePhone) {
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, phone);
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();

}
```

You can learn how to execute multiple statement in one shot, using [statement-batching](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)